# No Audio Output Device is installed

Tags: windows-vista, audio, troubleshooting, sound-card, sony-vaio

this is an intermitent problem in my Sony Vaio model PCG-5K1L. I keep on getting a "No Audio Output Device is installed" when hovering my loudspeaker icon in Windows Vista.

I have tried System >> Device Manager >> Sound >> Realtek High Definition Album >> Update Driver Software. The update process went through, but nothing happens. Still Vista does not seem to recognize my audio software.

The strange part is that out of nothing my sound card can resume working to stop again hours later... If someone has any clues to solve this, please, help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have an Acer Aspire 4520 that is facing the same problem. I'm at my wits' end.